# How to change the element at a row and column of a table in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

I re-read earlier posts on the subject and I thought that I implemented it correctly until it did not work. Is there a better way to change the element at a  row and column of a table in JavaScript?

From HTML:

```
  <table  class="center" border="3" id="checkersBoard">...
  <tr>
                 <td class="block"><img class="BlankSpace" src="Directory/BlankSpace.png"></td>  <td class="block"><img class="RedPiece" src="Directory/RedPiece.png"></td>  <td class="block"><img class="BlankSpace" src="Directory/BlankSpace.png"></td>  <td class="block"><img class="RedPiece" src="Directory/RedPiece.png"></td>  <td class="block"><img class="BlankSpace" src="Directory/BlankSpace.png"></td>  <td class="block"><img class="RedPiece" src="Directory/RedPiece.png"></td>  <td class="block"><img class="BlankSpace" src="Directory/BlankSpace.png"></td>  <td class="block"><img class="RedPiece" src="Directory/RedPiece.png"></td>
            </tr> // I know terrible but I was just copying and pasting from someone... will change later
```

From JavaScript:

```
var board = document.getElementById("checkersBoard");
var isRedHighlighted = false;
var isBlackHighlighted = false;
var lastClick;

board.addEventListener("click", function(e)
{
if(isBlackHighlighted || isRedHighlighted)
{
    if(isBlackHighlighted)
    {

        if(e.target.getAttribute('src') == "Directory/BlankSpace.png")
        {
           var targetLoc = {row :(e.target.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex+1), col :(e.target.parentNode.cellIndex+1) };
           var lastClickLoc = {row :(lastClick.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex +1), col :(lastClick.parentNode.cellIndex +1) };
            lastClick.src = "Directory/BlankSpace.png";
            e.target.src= "Directory/BlackPiece.png";

            if(lastClickLoc.row - 2 == targetLoc.row && lastClickLoc.col -2 == targetLoc.col)
            {
                alert('something should have happened');
                board.rows[(lastClickLoc.row)].cells[(lastClickLoc.col)].setAttribute('src',"Directory/BlankSpace.png" ); // why does this not work
                board.parentNode.rows[5].cells[5].src = "Directory/BlackPiece.png" // why does this not work
            }

            isBlackHighlighted = false;

        }
```

Comment: I would guess the last line in the if block doesn't work because whatever `board.parentNode` is doesn't have a `.rows` property. The second last line may have an indexing problem: why are you adding 1 to the row and column indexes?

Comment: edited to show a part of the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access an element at a given `row` and `col` you can use:

```
board.getElementsByTagName('tr')[row].getElementsByTagName('td')[col]
```

So you should change

```
board.rows[(lastClickLoc.row)].cells[(lastClickLoc.col)].setAttribute('src',"Directory/BlankSpace.png" );
board.parentNode.rows[5].cells[5].src = "Directory/BlackPiece.png"
```

to

```
board.getElementsByTagName('tr')[(lastClickLoc.row)].getElementsByTagName('td')[(lastClickLoc.col)].getElementsByTagName('img')[0].setAttribute('src',"Directory/BlankSpace.png" );
board.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('tr')[5].getElementsByTagName('td')[5].getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = "Directory/BlackPiece.png"
```

Comment: I'm sorry but the images still won't change... any other ideas how this is wrong?

Comment: Okay so the second line of code works when you remove the .parentNode. from the beginning.. but the first line is still having problems. -- Do you mind if I email you( the address in your profile's website) with all of my code and ask for a little more help?

Comment: Is `lastClickLoc` being set properly? Try using `console.log` to see what its value is right before the line that's having a problem. Edit: Yeah sure feel free to email me.